# Java - Inject String into Scanner

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

I have a method that uses a private `Scanner` that is initialized via `new Scanner(System.in);`

I call this method from a context in which I am trying to provide input to that `Scanner` instance as though I was a user of the program at the command line. For example, if I had the following function:

```
public void getColor(){
    ...
    System.out.print("Enter a color: ");
    scanner.next();
    ...
}
```

I would want to provide a color to `scanner`, which is an instance of `Scanner`, after calling `getColor()`. Is this possible in Java?

EDIT: Note that I was attempting to execute this in a test environment. That's probably a pretty important detail!

Comment: [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.InputStream)) takes an `InputStream` as parameter. Create your own stream, push your color onto it and you're done.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "pushing" the InputStream?

Comment: You could try to look at the [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class, that's all that comes to mind in that case.

Comment: Can you run some code *before* the Scanner is constructed? If so, you could use System.setIn() to provide an alternate standard input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using JUnit, and found that I could use [System Rules' TextFromStandardInputStream](http://www.stefan-birkner.de/system-rules/#TextFromStandardInputStream) utility in order to provide the exact amount and types of input to the `Scanner`.

However, for individuals who do not have access to JUnit, it appears as though  [System.setIn](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)() will get the job done just as well.

Comment: Huh? How are junit extensions going to help him? Also, I sorely doubt these junit extensions (which just work by calling System.setIn() ) would change what a previously initialized scanner sees.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I will once again endeavor to ask you to remove your downvote. I have modified my answer such that it explains how I got to my solution, and a solution that should work for others as well. Please let me know if there is something missing.

Comment: Sure. Sorry, I didn't realize this was a self-answer. If you were in a test environment already, you probably should have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: I appreciate it, and I will certainly add that detail to my question

Answer (score 0):

Use a ByteArrayInputStream. Get the bytes to construct it by calling String.getBytes() on your String of interest. Simple!

Comment: How exactly would the Scanner pick it up, though? It is a private variable.